# Recreating Host-Named Site Collection Fails To Show Site

Tags: powershell, site-collection, host-named

I have decided to go with [host-named site collections](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx) during our SharePoint 2013 migration and have been testing a single site collection to start and everything worked great.  I was able to add a CNAME record to my DNS and browse to my new host-named collection just fine.  BUT, since I am preparing PowerShell scripts to create the 24+ collections required for our migration, I delete the collection after a test, delete the content database, and start again.  Now, after I execute my script which creates the content database (SP2013_Content_3) and then creates the host-named site collection (http://hostnamedsite.ourdomain.com) and everything appears to be fine.  Until I attempt to browse to the new site.  When I do, I get just the HTTP header information for that site.  I tried browsing to the default page specifically and all I get is a blank page.  I look at the source of the page and it has just empty HTML tags.

Anyone have any ideas as to what I have done wrong?  Once a host-named collection is created, is there something special that has to happen to delete that site other than going to CA and deleting the site collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure what caused the problem, but I do know how to fix it.  I did an iisreset and everything is fine now.